# document.write resets body once

Tags: javascript, html, document

When I used document.write after loading the body (via onclick event), it overwrites the entire body. I want this for what I'm trying to achieve. However, when I do it again, it simply adds on to the previous content. Why does it overwrite everything the first time and only add on the next?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the document isn't open for writing, then calling `document.write` will automatically call `document.open`.

The first time you call `document.write`, the browser has loaded the document and thus closed it for writing. This calls `document.open` which wipes out the existing document and creates a new one to write into.

Since the browser isn't loading this, it doesn't automatically close it for writing, so the content is appended when you call `docment.write` again. You can explicitly call `document.close` and `document.open` if you want to wipe out the content.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.write for more details.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `document.write`, it writes directly to the page/body. If you want to write to some specific element, you can use syntax such as this:

```
document.getElementById('elementID').innerHTML = 'your string';
```

Comment: I need to use document.write because I'm trying to make a web page for a PlayStation Portable (PSP) web browser, which doesn't support DHTML however does support document.write.