# Why does Chrome's JavaScript console overwrite the existing html at first, but append after?

Tags: javascript

If I load a page with the following code:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        foo
    </body>
</html>
```

and launch Chrome's JavaScript console, and type:

```
document.writeln("bar");
```

it overwrites the existing page with "bar".  But if I then type:

```
document.writeln("baz");
```

it *appends* the text to the existing page.

Is this proper behavior, and why?  Is there any way to get the append behavior in the first place?

Comment: Yes, don't use `document.writeln()`.

Comment: Yes, use the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM).

Comment: possible duplicate of [document.write resets body once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511886/document-write-resets-body-once)